# Database ER design for calorie calculator app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-design, android-room

I'm making a very simple android app which lets a user plan meals for the day and calculates the total macros for the day.

The app should:

- create ingredients by providing a name, carbs, fat and protein content (per 100g) which should be saved in the database (Room)
- create Meals based on created ingredients
- persist both ingredients and meals in a database for future re-use

As an example, I would like to create an omelet meal to calculate its macros, so I add eggs, cheese, bacon and mushrooms by providing their per 100g content. Then I go to create my meal and do, add 120g of eggs, 100g of bacon, 30g of cheese and 50g of mushrooms.

My initial idea was to have Ingredient as an entity and then a Meal (another entity) would contain a list of ingredients. I am confused whether Meal should be a relation because a relation describes a relationship between two entities while this is more of a collection. How should I reflect this in my entity design?

Comment: What you're looking for is a one-to-many relationship between Meal and Ingredient. Note that relations (logical/mathematical structures) describe both entities and relationships (conceptual structures) and aren't limited to binary relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic many-to-many relation. A meal can have multiple ingredients and an ingredient can be in multiple meals.

So you need a mapping table.

```
ingredients table
-----------------
id (PK)
name
...


meals table
-----------
id (PK)
name


meal_ingredients table
----------------------
meal_id (FK)
ingredient_id (FK)
ingredient_amount
...
```

For every ingredient in your meal you would have a record in the `meal_ingredients` table.